# Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable error in Tinymce

Tags: vue.js, tinymce

I am using Tiny mce in my website since more than a year.
Today it suddenly stopped working and giving follwoing error
Anyonce can help to fix this error?
[image]

Comment: Are you doing something like `window.Event = ...` anywhere in your code? If so that's likely the cause, based on where the exception is being thrown. Doing that would be overriding the native browser `Event` object which could be breaking numerous things if it doesn't provide the same implementation as the browser.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, it just stopped working today. I can see that my textarea is not being updated and appears null when submitted to the controller. I have the same messages as you in the console. It appears to be a bug in the release they did overnight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Vue and followed the Laracasts tutorial to implement communication between components, you'll probably have this line in your main.js:

```
window.Event = new Vue();
```

The solution was to change that line to:

```
window.eventBus = new Vue({});
```

And then each of the places that was used, change

```
Event.$emit
```

to

```
window.eventBus.$emit
```

And:

```
Event.$on
```

to

```
window.eventBus.$on
```

I was pointed in the right direction by excellent support from Tiny. They also said that you can rollback to 5.8 while you resolve your problem by changing `/tinymce/5/` to `/tinymce/5.8/` in your `src`.